# Scipy t-test to measure the difference between the use of a lexicon in two documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I have following two documents of the indicated length.

```
 df_1.head()
                                             text  cat     word_count
 0  [india, education, commission, report, ma...     1         143615
 1  [national, education, policy, 2017, by, min...   2          30601
```

I am using a lexicon two measure the negative words in both documents and I get the following result in the `neg_scores` column. (1000 is for the count of the lexicon in each 1000 words)

```
def scores(text, lexicon):

count = sum([text.count(word) for word in lexicon])
score = count/len(text)*1000
print (text, score)
return score

df_1["neg_score"]=df_1.text.apply(lambda x: scores(x,neg_score))

df_1.head()
                                           text   cat  word_count neg_scores
 0  [india, education, commission, report, ma...    1     143615       0.065
 1  [national, education, policy, 2017, by, min...  2      30601       0.989
```

However, I want to calculate the scipy `t-test` to see the mean difference between both documents. The problem is I have only seemingly two observations although the number of words is higher than that. Is there any way I can calculate the t-test from Scipy considering words as my sample? Currently, I use the following codes and get these results.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
ttest_ind(df_1[df_1.cat==2].neg_scores, 
   df_1[df_1.cat==1].neg_scores)
```

> Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)

With Scipy's `scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats` feature I can calculate when I know the sample size, mean and variance of both documents. But how do I calculate this with lexicon?

Thank you.

Comment: You should ask for advice about the appropriate tests for this data over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  It doesn't look like a t-test is appropriate here.  Maybe make a contingency table and use the chi-square or G-test?  Bring it up on the other site.

Comment: Yes, you are right and thanks for pointing out this. I have indeed separated the documents into multiple rows to use t-test, but I guess using a chi square test would be more appropriate.